# Can't interact with services after installing istio 1.0.3

Tags: istio

I have used **istio-1.1.0-snapshot.2** and everything worked well. Then i have upgraded **istio to istio-1.0.3.** and after that i could not interact with services in mesh.

In logs of istio-ingressgateway i see such problems:

```
[2018-10-28 09:18:41.317][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/drain_manager_impl.cc:63] shutting down parent after drain
[2018-10-28 09:19:35.188][34][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/drain_manager_impl.cc:63] shutting down parent after drain
[2018-10-28 09:19:35.189][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/hot_restart_impl.cc:444] shutting down due to child request
[2018-10-28 09:19:35.189][20][warning][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:373] caught SIGTERM
[2018-10-28 09:19:35.189][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:436] main dispatch loop exited
[2018-10-28 09:19:35.197][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:472] exiting

[2018-11-02 09:22:33.045][34][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 13,
[2018-11-02 09:22:43.322][34][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
[2018-11-02 09:22:53.503][34][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
[2018-11-02 09:23:05.420][34][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
[2018-11-02 09:23:15.810][34][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers
```

Afeter executing command `istioctl proxy-status`, i have seen that versions of my side-car proxies if 1.0.2

Any suggestiongs?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading Istio control plane, you need to upgrade sidecar containers. In simple words, you need to re-inject them.

If you use manual injection, you can upgrade them by the command:

```
$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f $ORIGINAL_DEPLOYMENT_YAML)
```

If you use automatic sidecar injection, you can upgrade the sidecar by doing a rolling update for all the pods, so that the new version of the sidecar will be automatically re-injected.

Here is the [link](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/upgrading-istio/#sidecar-upgrade) on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1.0.3 Appears to be rather broke, it doesn't route requests between containers. Even a simple wordpress/mysql site does not work in 1.0.3